# Scraping Google Scholar with urllib2 instead of requests

Tags: python, python-requests, google-scholar

I have the simple script below which works just fine for fetching a list of articles from Google Scholar searching for a term of interest.

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

SEARCH_SCHOLAR_HOST = "https://scholar.google.com"
SEARCH_SCHOLAR_URL = "/scholar"

def searchScholar(searchStr, limit=10):
    """Search Google Scholar for articles and publications containing terms of interest"""
    url = SEARCH_SCHOLAR_HOST + SEARCH_SCHOLAR_URL + "?q=" + urllib.quote_plus(searchStr) + "&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&btnG=Search"
    content = requests.get(url, verify=False).text
    page = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
    results = {}
    count = 0
    for entry in page.find_all("h3", attrs={"class": "gs_rt"}):
        if count < limit:
            try:
                text = entry.a.text.encode("ascii", "ignore")
                url = entry.a['href']
                results[url] = text 
                count += 1
            except:
                pass
    return results

queryStr = "Albert einstein"
pubs = searchScholar(queryStr, 10)
if len(pubs) == 0:
    print "No articles found"
else:   
    for pub in pubs.keys():
        print pub + ' ' + pubs[pub]
```

However, I want to run this script as a CGI application on a remote server, without access to console, so I cannot install any external Python modules. (I managed to 'install' BeautifulSoup without resorting to pip or easy_install by just copying the bs4 directory to my cgi-bin directory, but this trick does not worked with requests because of its large amount of dependencies.)

So, my question is: is it possible to use the built-in urllib2 or httplib Python modules instead of requests for fetching the Google Scholar page and then pass it to BeautifulSoup? It should be, because I found some code [here](https://github.com/1ucian0/chalmers-web/tree/master/scholar) which scrapes Google Scholar using just the standard libraries plus BeautifulSoup, but it is rather convoluted. I would prefer to achieve a much simpler solution, just be adapting my script for using the standard libraries instead of requests.

Could anyone give me some help?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend scrapping Google Scholar as they disallow bots. You can get banned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is enough to perform a simple request using [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html):

```
def get(url):
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/2.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)')
    return urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
```

if you need to do something more advanced in the future it will be more code. What request does is simplifies the usage over that of the standard libs.

Comment: ... but not completely! As it should be expected, Gugly blocks the execution of the code when it is run on the server (locally it works fine).

Comment: @maurobio It’s possibly captcha, because you havent verified you’re a human on the servers ip